# there is a white margin on the right side of my site

Tags: css, wordpress, margin, space

There ARE other questions regarding this issue. However, each one seems to have an individual answer, because the answers found do not work.

Just scroll right on my site and see the white space all through the site: http://highcatering.wpengine.com/

NOT nice!

Any ideas? I have tried the following:

```
body{width:100%;}
body{margins:0 0 0 0;}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `margins` is not valid css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is in style.css:

```
.post ol, .post ul { margin:0 0 30px 20px; padding:0;}
```

It is adding a margin to all `ol` and `ul` within your main body section. If you remove it, the white space will disappear. I'm not sure if it is needed somewhere else on your site.

Comment: I will try deleting it.

Comment: MAGNIFIC! Thank you, @avalera. Problem solved. Nothing else seemed to be affected.

Answer (score 0):

That large white bar down there, is a place to insert some widgets, if you do not want to use this section, add this on your CSS file:

```
.footerWrap.footerStyleLight {
    display: none;
}
```

If you want to have something on this section later but with a different background color, just change the background color like this for example:

```
.footerWrap.footerStyleLight {
    background: #2c2c2c;
}
```

Although you probably have this class in your CSS file, search for it delete what's inside and add this `display: none;` or for changing background color `background: #2c2c2c;`

Comment: Chun, I tried it, but it only looks nicer; the margin problem is still there.

Comment: So what's your goal? to remove that white bar at the bottom of the website?

Comment: I wanted to remove a white space at the right side of my site. @Alavera pointed out a nice solution. Now, you saw a white space at the bottom of my site, that I hadn't noticed. I used your suggestion and now the white space at the bottom is fixed. Thank you, Chun!

Answer (score 0):

it should be like:

```
body
{
width:100%;
margin:0;
}
```

Comment: Alex, I added that code to the stylesheet and nothing happened D:

Comment: Could you please post the entire HTML/CSS in http://jsfiddle.net/? As a general rule, check out all margin/padding CSS statement. Also, .columns1_2 { width: 90%; margin: 0 1.5% 0 2.0%;} should be: .columns1_2 { width: 90%; margin: 0% 1.5% 0% 2.0%;}. Rgds,

Comment: Alex, the issue was solved minutes ago by alavera. Thank you a lot, a will correct that statement. :D